# Get items from list where index not equal to an int using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have items in a `List`and I want to get all the items which index is not equal to something,

Say it's a list of button `List<Button>`. How do I get those buttons with index other than `index` using something like the following.

```
var buttons = buttonList.Where(b => b<indexOfbutton> != index);
```

**Update:**

I am trying to get `<indexOfButton>` in one line. So I assume there's another linq query to get the button index from buttonList?

The end goal is to get List which does not contain the index in question.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the question completely. Is the end goal here to have a List<Button> which does not contain the index in question, as well as the indexOfButton? The indexOfButton would be a list of indices which did not equal the provided index, correct?

Comment: The end goal is to get `List<Button>` which does not contain the index in question.

Comment: I think Selman22 and hazzik have two answers which will both accomplish that. Selman22's answer will not modify the original list, and hazzik's answer will. I'm still a little confused about getting the indexOfButton. I think the assumption here is that you already know the index in question, and it is stored in the "index" variable.

Comment: No it does not store in a variable. I have to query the index of that button too from buttonList. Otherwise it will be as easy as `var buttons = buttonList.Where(b => b.index != index);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the *index* within lambda expression because there is an another overload of [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that takes an `Func<TSource, int, bool>` :

> `System.Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>`
>
> A function to test each source element for a condition; *the second
>   parameter of the function represents the index of the source element.*

```
var buttons = buttonList.Where((b,idx) => idx != index);
```

You can also write an extension method for that:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int index)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (counter != index)
                yield return item;

            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
var buttons = buttonList.SkipIndex(index).ToList();
```

If you want to get buttons with their indices:

```
var buttons = buttonList
              .Select((b,idx) => new { Button = b, Index = idx })
              .Where(x => x.Index != index)
              .ToList();
```

This will return you a list of anonymous types that contains two properties, one of them is your button and the other one it's index.

Answer (score 2):

If I have throw-away list (if I do not need the *original* list and only list without an element) and the buttonList is `IList<>`, I would use something like

```
buttonList.RemoveAt(index);
```

Comment: This would be an efficient method for removing the item with that index from the List. Note that this will actually change the List, though (I'm assuming that's what you're getting at with "throw-away").

Comment: it's now a throw-away list

Comment: @dvlsg, yes, it is what I mean by "throw-away"

Comment: I would select this as an answer if it's a throw-away list (but the list shouldn't be changed in my case). I like that it's straight forward.